# Display searchbar and search results on different html pages using AJAX

Tags: javascript, c#, html, ajax, algolia

I have a searchbar/menu at the top of my website. I made this top bar into a template (called `_Layouts.cshtml`) so that I render the top bar on every html page regardless of the body content. The searchbar and results are created using javascript at the bottom of my `_Layouts.cshtml`:

```
<script>
        //Algolia Search JS
        const search = instantsearch({
            appId: 'MYID',
            apiKey: 'MYAPI',
            indexName: 'unearth',
            urlSync: true
        });

        search.addWidget(
            instantsearch.widgets.searchBox({
                container: '#search-box',
                placeholder: 'Search by artist, mood, bpm, or genre...'
            })
        );

        search.addWidget(
            instantsearch.widgets.hits({
                container: '.artist-search-result',
                templates: {
                    empty: 'No results',
                    item: "<img src='/resources/images/flume_prof_pic.jpg'><div class='search-result-meta'><h3>{{{artist}}}</h3><h3 class='search-result-type'>Artist</h3></div>"           
                }
            })
        );

        search.start();
        //End Algolia Search JS
    </script>
```

**When I click on the search bar to search for an item, I load the search results page using AJAX.**

```
$(function () {
    $("#search-box").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "home/search", success: function (result) {
                //$(".body-container").html(result);
                $('.body-container').html($(result).find('.search-results-container').html());
            }
        });

    });
});
```

The issue I have run into is that both the `searchBox` and `hits` widgets need to be on the same html page because when I separate the `#search-box` in my `_Layouts.cshtml` like this:

```
<div id="search-box">
<!-- Search bar is generated here -->
</div>
```

and the search results in my `Search.cshtml` like so:

```
<div class="artist-search-result">
<!-- results are generated here -->
</div>
```

The search bar doesn't render since it cannot find the container `.artist-search-result`because this class is rendered via AJAX and only shows up on the DOM once the `Search.cshtml` AJAX call is made.

[image]

What would be the best approach to fix this?

For clarity, here's my UX flow:

User is on home page -> click searchbar at top of page to search for item -> the body content loads the search results page via AJAX -> user types search query -> results display on the ajax rendered page.

I can confirm this is the issue, because if I load up the Search.cshtml directly from the browswer, the search bar renders and I can see my results properly since the `.artist-search-result` class exists on initial DOM load

Answer (score 0):

What you can do here is:

1. Define all your dom containers. You can then have a styled search input but the hits hidden.
2. Then, you can start instantsearch.js js when there is a click on the searchbox but still keep the hits hidden.
3. At the first key stroke, you can then display the hits.